# How to make a realtime crud using vuex and socketio?

Tags: node.js, express, vue.js, socket.io, vuex

I want to perform a realtime crud using vuex, node, express and socketio but using the following syntax I can't get the result.

**Server**

**index.js**

```
const server = app.listen('3000',() => {
    console.log('<--- Web Server Starter --->')
    const io = require('./sockets')(server)
    io.on('connection', socket=>{
        console.log('client connected');
    })
})
```

**socket.js**

```
    let io
    module.exports = {
        init:httpServer =>{
            io = require('socket.io')(httpServer)
            return io
        },
        getIo:()=>{ 
            if(!io){
                throw new Error('socket io not initialized')
            }
            return io
        }
    }
```

**user.js**

```
const io = require('../socket')
router.post('/newuser',(req, res) => {
    res.json({ serverResponse: 'userCreated' })
    io.getIo().emit('newuser',{serverResponse:'created',user:user})
})
```

**Client**

**Module user.js (VUEX actions)**

```
getusers({ commit }){
    const sessionToken = localStorage.getItem('sessionToken')
    axios.get('/newuser', {
        headers: {
            Authorization: `Bearer ${localStorage.getItem('sessionToken')}`
        },
    })
        .then(response => {
            const socket = openSocket('http://localhost:3000')
            socket.on('newuser', data => {
                if (data.serverResponse === 'created') {
                    this.users = data.user
                    commit('GET_USERS', users)
                })
        })
        .catch(error => {
            alert(error)
        })
})
```

When I create the new user, the user list is not updated automatically, but I have to refresh the page to see the new user, why does this happen?

Comment: resetting my headers  solves the problem in some cases , window.axios.defaults.headers.common = {
                            'Authorization': `Bearer ${localStorage.getItem('sessionToken')}`
                        }

Answer (score 0):

This is because in your backend you are handling the post url-endpoint `'/newuser'` to get the data. You are not actually posting the data using socketio, therefore if you don't update the page, your `axios.get` function isn't going to have any new data to get until the API you are posting to has refreshed. It would be better to put your socket client code outside of the axios promise so that the data is primarily updated on the client by socketio and not by the API.

**EDIT:**
This is the code for it in your client

```
    getusers({
  commit
}) {
  const sessionToken = localStorage.getItem('sessionToken')
  axios.get('/newuser', {
      headers: {
        Authorization: `Bearer ${localStorage.getItem('sessionToken')}`
      },
    })
    .then(response => {
      console.log('success');
    })
    .catch(error => {
      alert(error)
    })

  const socket = openSocket('http://localhost:3000')
  socket.on('newuser', data => {
      if (data.serverResponse === 'created') {
        this.users = data.user
        commit('GET_USERS', users)
      })
  })
```

You had a problem with your .catch part of the promise as it was inside the .then part and I also moved your socket code outside of the promise.

Comment: maybe this could be the solution,please show me with code

Answer (score -1):

So in your server when you post to /newuser. you send emit from the socketio
on your client you dont need to use axios to check if some socket events has been fired, try to remove the axios.get() and keep

```
 const socket = openSocket('http://localhost:3000')
   socket.on('newuser', data => {
   //do some thing             
   })
```